# div same height with floats

Tags: html, css

It seems this issue has been addressed earlier, but none of the solutions seem to work for me.

My current situation:
container div set as `display:table-row`
children are set as `display:table-cell`

all the children now have the same height, as I want to.

My problem:
when the window gets resized, not all the divs are visible. How can I make sure the divs are always visible. examples:

Resize progress:

```
DIV#1 ---- DIV#2 ---- DIV#3 ---- DIV#4 ---- DIV#5



DIV#1 ---- DIV#2 ---- DIV#3 ---- DIV#4 
DIV#5


DIV#1 ---- DIV#2 ---- DIV#3
DIV#4 ---- DIV#5
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9BC53/2/

*I hope this can be solved without the use of JavaScript*

*EDIT* I don't want to specify any height. The div's must be as long as the longest sibling.

Comment: Something like this? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9BC53/3/)

Comment: @Mr_Green ah sorry I forgot to mention I don't want to specify any height. I just want the div's to be the height of the longest DIV

Comment: check my updated post below.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `display: table-row` or `display: table-cell`.

**CSS**

```
div#main {
    display: inline-block;
    /* to clear float */
    overflow: hidden;
}
div.elem {
    float: left;
    background:#ff0000;
    /* same height as intented */
    text-align: center;
    width: 80px;
}
div.elem div {
    width:40px;
}
div#one div {
    background:#111;
}
div#two div {
    background:#444;
}
div#three div {
    background:#777;
}
div#four div {
    background:#aaa;
}
div#five div {
    background:#ddd;
}
```

**Javascript**:

```
var main = document.getElementById('main');
var height = main.offsetHeight + "px";
var children = main.children;
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    var c = children[i];
    c.style.height = height;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9BC53/7/)**

Comment: No.. I think what op is looking for is **My problem: when the window gets resized, not all the divs are visible. How can I make sure the divs are always visible.**

Comment: It almost works as I would like to. But when I resize the browser, DIV#5 comes below DIV#3, and I want it to go below DIV#1 (see my examples in the original post)

Comment: @AngeloA Then I think it is possible if you include javascript. Updated my post.

Comment: @Mr_Green Yes, thank you. It works, unfortunately with JS, but I think that's my only and best option (for now). I'll upvote your answer, but I won't mark is as accepted answer. Thanks for your help though!